# How to make div full width of screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make div which take 100% of width and hight of the screen and it may also responsive -

it gives output like this -
[image]

```css
* {
  top: 0%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Imprima', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: #D5C5C6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: self-start;
  gap: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="nev" id="nevbar"></div>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="heading">Beauty Brands</div>
    <div class="description">Treat your makeup like jewelry for the face. Play with colors, shapes, structure It can transform you.</div>
    <div class="ctc-btn"><a href="">Get Offer</a></div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div id="brand">Brands</div> -->

  <div class="footer">www.logo.com</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "responsive", but you can fill the viewport with a div by using `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw`.  You may also want to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veEqYQlfNx8&ab_channel=KevinPowell) for some tips/pitfalls with this approach.

Comment: @jake, making a div `100vh` and `100vw` does not make it fill the screen alone. You will make the screen overflow. Most vital for that procedure to work is to reset the default body margin! On top of that, you should always use `min-height` or add an overflow rule to prevent overflow issues.

Comment: Also read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height: 100%` means 100% of the parent element's height.

The default height of block-level elements is `fit-content`. `fit-content` means, that the height is `undefined` but will be calculated to fit the content of the element.

If we combine both pieces of information together, you will realize that 100% of undefined is still undefined. As such `100%` only works with a specifically defined height.

What you actually want to use are the values `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height)  which are units relative to the size of the viewport. The viewport is the visual area of a web browser (not the screen size).

However, to work correctly, you need to add a few things to prevent overflow issues.

1. You need to reset the default body margin as otherwise you would overflow by 2 x 8px : `body { margin: 0; }`.
2. The element that should fit the entire screen must set the box model to `border-box` as otherwise padding or border would also overflow the screen as those are normally calculated on top of the width and height of the element.
3. You need to use either `min-height` or an overflow rule to that element as otherwise a larger content would overflow the element and collide with other content.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Imprima', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #D5C5C6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: self-start;
  gap: 120px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="nev" id="nevbar"></div>

  <div class="hero">
    <div class="heading">Beauty Brands</div>
    <div class="description">Treat your makeup like jewelry for the face. Play with colors, shapes, structure It can transform you.</div>
    <div class="ctc-btn"><a href="">Get Offer</a></div>
  </div>

  <!-- <div id="brand">Brands</div> -->

  <div class="footer">www.logo.com</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `vw` and `vh` css units which respond to the size of the screen, they works like the percentage unit.

`vw` is according to the width of the screen size.
Specify 10vw is to take up 10% of the total viewable screen width.

`vh` is according to the height of the screen size.
Specify 10vh is to take up 10% of the total viewable screen height.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-css-units-em-rem-vh-vw-with-code-examples/

Comment: `vw` and `vh` are not units that respond to the size of the screen! They are equivalent to the viewports sizes. The difference is that the viewport is only the part of the browser that is reserved for the content. A browser must not necessarily be operated in full screen nor does it utilize the full hight of a screen. However you going to miss on the most crucial side information as of now you would just overflow the screen.